# GtkLabel print formated double value

Tags: gtk

I have a label with number in text output:

```
double freq;
    .....................................................

buf = g_strdup_printf(_("Checking %6.2f MHz"), freq))
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), buf);
g_free(buf);
```

text is displayed in gtklabel without respect format specifiers like in this example:

print numbers aligned to the left:

```
Checking 88.40 MHz
Checking 95.10 MHz
Checking 102.20 MHz
```

instead of right alignment:

```
Checking  88.40 MHz
Checking  95.10 MHz
Checking 102.20 MHz
```

There is a way to be respected this required formated string: %6.2f like function printf output (stdout).

I did a quick terminal test and the formatting is correct.
What I may want to check is the font used to display text in the GtkLabel. If the font is not mono-space then the "Space" character is very much smaller and may be extra smaller when two space characters are placed together. I use default [ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/). But if in the terminal is displayed correctly should be applied correctly also to gtk?

Comment: `"Checking %0.2f MHz"` (align left) or `"Checking %-6.2f MHz"`  (align left, but still 6 wide)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the label is using a proportional font where spaces are very thin. To fix that, switch to [`gtk_label_set_markup`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-markup) and use [pango markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) to specify fixed-width font for the numeric part of the string:

```
buf = g_strdup_printf(_("Checking <tt>%6.2f</tt> MHz"), freq))
gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(label), buf);
g_free(buf);
```